# Why are my images getting saved somewhere else other than the directory specified?

Tags: python, image, directory, google-colaboratory, video-processing

I am currently getting frames out of my input video and want to save it in a specific folder (in colab). But instead of the folder specified, the images are getting saved outside of the folder.

This is my code.

```
  while (True):
    vidcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,(count*1000)) 
    success,image = vidcap.read()
    print ('Read a new frame: ', count)
    name = './data'+ str(current_time) + '.jpg'  #This is where I have specified my folder
    cv2.imwrite(name, image)  
    count = count + 1

extractImages()
```

The images should be getting saved in the folder called data. But that isnt happening

Where am i going wrong? And what do i have to do to save the images into the /content/data folder.

Comment: you are missing "/" here. try some thing like this name = './data/'+ str(current_time) + '.jpg'

Comment: Or even simpler `'data/' + str(current_time) + '.jpg'` since, by definition, you are always in `.` because it means *"the current directory"*.